# cannot assign value of type '[(string, string)]' to type '[string : string]'

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I've declared this dictionary:

```
var arrayFrasi:[String:String] = [:]
```

Then in the viewDidLoad I retrive the data from my db and then I sort the dictionary using this code:

```
let df = NSDateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

        let myArrayOfTuples = self.arrayFrasi.sort{ df.dateFromString($0.0)!.compare(df.dateFromString($1.0)!) == .OrderedAscending}
```

But I need to use the initial dictionary (*arrayFrasi)*, when I do this:

```
self.arrayFrasi = myArrayOfTuples
```

I've got this error:

> cannot assign value of type '[(string, string)]' to type '[string : string]'

I can't figure out why. Thank you very much!

Comment: The .sort function on dictionaries returns an array of tuples.  You're then trying to assign that to a dictionary, which won't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That makes perfect sense. A Dictionary has no defined order, so the `sort` returns you an array of tuples.

> Swift’s Dictionary type does not have a defined ordering. To iterate
>   over the keys or values of a dictionary in a specific order, use the
>   sort() method on its keys or values property.

*https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html*

Answer (score 0):

You need to Map it back into the same type

```
var arrayFrasi: [String: String] = [ "24-01-1991" : "VALUE" , "22-01-1991" : "VALUE" ]
let df = NSDateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

let myArrayOfTuples = arrayFrasi.sort{ df.dateFromString($0.0)!.compare(df.dateFromString($1.0)!) == .OrderedAscending}.map { [$0.0 : $0.1] }.flatMap { $0 }
    .reduce([String:String]()) { (dict, tuple) in
        var dict = dict
        dict.updateValue(tuple.1, forKey: tuple.0)
        return dict
}

arrayFrasi = myArrayOfTuples // ["22-01-1991": "VALUE", "24-01-1991": "VALUE"]
```

Hope It Helps

Comment: This doesn't buy you anything.  You can't have a sorted dictionary, so in the end all of the work is for naught.

Comment: Yes, Its a key value pair. It doesn't need to be sorted because its not indexed. Instead its hashed for fast access. I should add that.

Comment: With your method if I print the arrayFrasi dictionary the elements are not ordered!